# Access Wifi From Dock on a House Boat

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

My dad has a houseboat on a lake.  The dock that he is at offers free WiFi for the house boat users.  However, the antenna is about 150-200 feet away and he is unable to get a signal strong enough to connect to.

He would like to be able to extend the WiFi network so that him and his guests can easily connect to the WiFi network from anywhere on his boat.  What does he need to purchase to be able to do this?  He is not allowed to modify any of the dock's equipment so the solution has to be equipment that he can install on his boat.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember, Wi-Fi is a two way protocol. The problem could be with the radios/antenna in his PC, not the radio/antenna in the WAP. This is only one possibility. This could be a complex problem. Hiring someone to do a wireless survey will shed light on the real problem.

Comment: Well, if you're going to accept the answer, then you're going to have to invite me to visit the houseboat!  ;^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install a wireless router in the boat.  That'll give you coverage of the boat.  The next issue is how to connect WAN input on the router to the wireless signal coming from the dock.  While there are a lot of ways to do that, I find Ubiquity equipment to be pretty excellent.  You might just get a Bullet M - Titanium, maybe, 'cause he's out there on the water - and a mast antenna.  You don't want anything too focused for the antenna, given that you're on a boat and there will at least be drift, if not outright rocking.  So stay away from the parabolic dishes or the yagis.  Probably just a mast/"omni" antenna would do, and at that distance 12dBi would probably be sufficient.

[Ubiquity at Streakwave](https://www.streakwave.com/product-ubiquiti.asp), for example.  Look for Bullet M in the products list.  M2 is for 2.4GHZ band, M5 for the 5GHZ band.  HP means it puts out a higher power level, which you may or may not need.

[Omni antennas at Streakwave](https://www.streakwave.com/items.asp?Cc=ANT2%2E4OM&iTpStatus=0&Tp=&Bc=)

The Bullet will screw on to the base of the antenna (make sure they are both N-type connectors and the proper Male/Female relationship).  That will be set into "base-station" mode.  The Bullet will then connect to the router using regular cat-5e cable.  Get some external cable so it's waterproof.

I do the same thing connecting to a university wireless from my roof, though I use a Ubiquity Nanobridge which comes with an 18dBi dish.

Do notice that I've used "probably" and the like.  Wireless is a bit of an art form.  You may have to play.

That's it!  Have fun.